# Selecting from table to insert into another, getting a type error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query which inserts data into one table after selecting it from another.

The problem is that the data types do not match for one of the columns. I have simplified the query below.

```
INSERT INTO tbl.LogTable (
    [SelPartNo], -- This does not match, see below
    )
SELECT TOP 1 
    IF([SelPartNo] = 'False', NULL, [SelPartNo],
FROM tbl.MyTable
WHERE ID = '20358'
ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
```

The first `SelPartNo` is an int and the second is a `VarChar`. In most instances the `SelPartNo` for the second one (`tbl.MyTable`) is `NULL` or an integer, which I don't think will cause a problem. But in some cases the value is "False", which needs to return `NULL`.

I have tried an IF statement but I am doing something wrong because it's giving a syntax error and I am unsure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: You have a missing parenthesis.  Is this really the verbatim code which you tried running on SQL Server?

Comment: Also, `IF` should be `IIF`.

Comment: This is simplified code. It is line #5 that I need help with.

Comment: @Shnugo Forgot to do this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is syntactically incorect...

Try it with

```
NULLIF([SelPartNo],'False')
```

This function returns `NULL` if the two expressions are equal.

Details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `IF` is a function, at least not one which you can use in a `SELECT` statement.  But `CASE WHEN ... END` is your friend:

```
INSERT INTO tbl.LogTable (
    [SelPartNo]
    )
SELECT TOP 1 
    CASE WHEN [SelPartNo] = 'False' THEN NULL ELSE [SelPartNo] END
FROM tbl.MyTable
WHERE ID = '20358'
ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
```